# ¿como puedo hacer que el código continué cuando ya se ingreso el nombre?

Tags: java

```
//datos
        //nombre

        String teclado1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,  "Cual es tu nombre" , "nombre", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        String dato_nom=teclado1;

        if (dato_nom!=" ") {



        }else { 

            while(dato_nom==" ") {

            String teclado3=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,  "intentalo de nuevo" , "nombre", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

//aun que ingreso un nombre el bucle se sigue ejecutando ¿por que?

                }

         }
```

Comment: Ese codigo no va a funcionar correctamente nunca. La comparación de Strings es con equals no con ==

Comment: Como te comentan debes hacer la comparación con el método `equals`. También tu código continua independientemente de si ingresas un nombre o no. Yo lo haría con un `do - while` de una manera más sencilla y sin ningún `if o else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice el compañero @JDev, en este caso no te funciona correctamente el programa por..

> a la hora de hacer la comparación con el **`==`**, solo los tipos primitivos se comparan así, es más, el código continua independientemente de si ingresas un nombre o no.

Por ello debes utilizar el método [public boolean equals​(Object anObject)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

---

Un programa sencillo de lo que estás intentado realizar sería este:

```
String dato_nom="";

        do{
            String teclado1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,  "Cual es tu nombre" , "nombre", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            dato_nom=teclado1;

        } while(dato_nom.equals(""));

        System.out.println("Tu nombre es: "+ dato_nom);
```

En el cual siempre nos pedirá una primera vez ingresar el nombre, y en el caso de no ingresar ninguno, nos mantendrá la ventanita del JOptionPane hasta que hayamos ingresado algo.

Answer (score 1):

Tu bucle se sigue ejecutando por que la variable `dato_nom` siempre tiene el mismo valor y por tanto la condición para que el bucle se ejecute siempre se cumple.

Para parar el bucle que planteas deberías cambiar, dentro del propio bucle, el valor de la variable que usas como condición para que el bucle se repita. Es decir, que la variable `dato_nom` deje de ser igual a `" "`.

Yo plantearía el bucle de otra manera:

```
while (teclado1.isEmpty()) {
        teclado1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,  "Cual es tu nombre" , "nombre", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: La condicion no se cumple nunca pues esta mal la comparación. Para Strings se debe comparar con equals no con ==

Comment: @JDev . Si no me equivoco, en caso de tipos de datos primitivos puedes compararlo con `==`, para objetos es cuando se debe usar `equals()`, como bien comentas, o usar las interfaces `Comparable` o `Comparator`. En este caso tienes razón con que no va a funcionar tal y como esta planteado.

Comment: Tipos primitivos si, pero String no lo es, es un Objeto y se debe usar equals.